# Not able to set the relative position of Divs

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, sass

I am doing a Analog clock project in React, Typescript and SCSS. My objective is to write as much CSS in the SCSS file and inline CSS minimally. (or not at all).

I wrote this SCSS file

```
.dial-style {
  position: 'relative';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200;
  height: 200;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000;
}

.second-hand-style {
  position: 'relative';
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40%;
  height: 1;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.minute-hand-style {
  position: 'relative';
  top: 100;
  left: 100;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 40%;
  height: 3;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  background-color: grey;  
}

.hour-hand-style {
  position: 'relative';
  top: 100;
  left: 100;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 20%;
  height: 7;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  background-color: #808080;
}
```

And my Typescript React component looks like

```
import * as React from 'react'
import '../styles/style'

export class AnalogClock extends React.Component<AnalogClockProps, AnalogClockState> {
  constructor(props: AnalogClockProps) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    let secondsTransform = {
      transform: 'rotate(' + ((this.props.currentTime.getSeconds() * 6) - 90).toString() + 'deg)'
    }
    let minuteAngle = (this.props.currentTime.getMinutes() * 6) + (this.props.currentTime.getSeconds() / 60)
    let minutesTransform = {
      transform: 'rotate(' + (minuteAngle - 90).toString() + 'deg)'
    }
    let hoursAngle = (this.props.currentTime.getHours() * 30) + (this.props.currentTime.getMinutes() / 2)
    let hoursTransform = {
      transform: 'rotate(' + (hoursAngle - 90).toString() + 'deg)'
    }    
    return (
      <div className="dial-style">
        <div className="second-hand-style" style={secondsTransform} />
        <div className="minute-hand-style" style={minutesTransform} />
        <div className="hour-hand-style" style={hoursTransform} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

interface AnalogClockState {}
interface AnalogClockProps {
  currentTime: Date
}
```

My clock appears like

[image]

No matter what I put for top, left, width, height. the position of the hands of the clock does not change at all. it just remains pinned at the top of the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you share a working code ? there is a lot of error in your CSS : relative shouldn't bet within `'` and top/left/height should have a unit

Comment: https://github.com/abhsrivastava/react-ts-clock

Comment: am pretty sure if you correct your CSS it will be fine

Comment: its my day 3 with CSS. I am trying to change properties for top, left, height width.... but the hands remain in the top left corner of the screen.

Comment: because you need unit ... since it's  your day 3 then you may read more about CSS and how to correctly use it

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch Like Termani said, remove the `'` around `relative` and add a unit to your `height`, `width`, `top` and `left`. '100' is not a valid unit, it's either 100% or 100px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add units to `width`, `height`, `top` and `left`. I reckon you're trying to use pixels, then add `px`:

```
top: 100px;
```

Also, no quotation marks in `'relative'`:

```
position: relative;
```

Comment: yes it worked instantly when I removed those single quotes.